# A question of the product of a complex matrix and a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Dear mathematics community, I got a question in an exam paper of linear algebra :

$A$ is a complex matrix, $B$ is a nilpotent matrix, and $AB = BA$, prove that $|A+2010B| = |A|$.

Here is my solution: suppose $l$ is the index of $B$, multiply $|B|^{l-1}$ at each side of $|A+2010B| = |A|$, then eliminate $|B|^{l-1}$, done. The condition of  $AB = BA$ seems redundant. Is my solution correct ? Is that condition really redundant?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $|A|$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг determinant of A

Comment: Ah, I see, fine.

Comment: What happens if $|B| = 0$?

Comment: No, your solution is incorrect.  Nilpotent matrices are not invertible so $|B| = |B|^{\ell -1} = 0$.

Comment: @Qudit Yes, I just realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that $AB=BA$ is essential. Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$
and $B=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$.

If $A$ is invertible, then
$$\det(A+\lambda B)=\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}B).$$
As $A$ and $B$ commute, $A^{-1}B$ is nilpotent, so $\det(I+A^{-1}B)=1$.

If $A$ is not invertible, then consider $A'=A+xI$ where $x$ is an indeterminate. By the above $\det(A'+\lambda B)=\det(A')$
whenever $\det(A+xI)\ne0$, so for all but finitely many $x$. But
$\det(A'+\lambda B)$ and $\det(A')$ are polynomials in $x$, so
they are equal for $x=0$ too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've figured out where my solution go wrong: I eliminate zero at each side of an equation. :(

Comment: My understanding is like this:the two polynomials are equal because there are infinite such $x$, then they are equal for $x=0$. Did I get your answer the right way?